# cross platform application testing

Tags: gratis, cross-platform, software-testing

I recently created an app (executable) for all of Windows and iOS devices. However I didn't had the chance to actually test it on all of them. So my question is if there is any software that will allow me to test the executable file across the different OS's.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What technologies did you use, is it a web app, iOS app, what do you want to test (UI, if it works) etc.

Comment: it is a gui created on python

Comment: Are you looking for a free application or can it be commercial? What technology does it use for the UI (Tk, Qt, ...)?

Comment: looking for free software; technology used is only Tk()

Comment: I added the [tag:gratis] tag for you (free software, but not necessarily [tag:open-source]). Please remember that the more info you give us, the better we can help you (GIGO (no offence intended)). Someone could have spent a long time posting an answer that costs $99, for you to reply "must be free". That person is unlikely to help you in future (or others, if it happens too often). Good question, though (upvoted)

Answer (score 1):

If your application has no graphic user interface there's a `unittest` Python module that will work accross all platforms.

When it comes to the UI you'll find that the underlying programming language is less relevant than the GUI technology. What counts is the nature of the GUI objects instantiated. A test tool can access them via their native API independent of the source language.

The [Squish GUI Tester](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/) tool supports testing of cross-platform Python applications on Windows, iOS and other desktop and mobile platforms. No matter whether the UI technology if Web, Qt or a native one like WPF or Cocoa.

Disclaimer: I'm employed by the maker of this tool. I'm here in my spare time right now, though.